# Livetime for JWT tokens issued by CAS Server

Tags: cas

It looks like CAS can issue JWT Token after login:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configure-ServiceTicket-JWT.html

I have two questions about this functionality:

1. It is possible to configure live time (expiration) for JWT Tokens ?
2. It is possible to refresh such tokens on backend (using refresh token)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expiration time of the generated JWT is controlled by the length of the assertion returned as part of the validation event. If the assertion validity length is not specified, then the expiration time is controlled by the length of the SSO session defined as part of SSO expiration policy of the CAS server.

**Not OpenID Connect**

Remember that you are just receiving a ticket in form of a JWT, thereby removing the need from your client to validate a normal service ticket. The ticket is internally validated by CAS and you as the client are only left in charge of validating the JWT itself. Do not confuse this with OpenID Connect. While a JWT, the token itself is not an ID token, cannot be refreshed and must be obtained again once you deem it expired. If you need more, consider using the OpenID Connect protocol instead.

Comment: NOTE: This applies to 5.2.X version.